# How can GetFreeDiskSpaceEx return the (seemingly) wrong amount of disk space?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, diskspace

So I work on a device that outputs large images (anywhere from 30MB to 2GB+).  Before we begin creating one of these images we check to see if there is sufficient disk space via `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx`.  Typically (and in this case) we are writing to a shared folder on the same network.  There are no user quotas on disk space at play.

Last night, in preparation for a demo, we kicked off a test run.  During the run we experienced a failure.  We needed `327391776` bytes and were told that we only had `186580992` available.  The numbers from `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` were:

> User free space available: 186580992
>
> Total free space available: 186580992

Those correspond to the `QuadPart` variables in the two (output) arguments `lpFreeBytesAvailable` and `lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes` to `GetDiskFreeSpaceAvailable`.

This code has been in use for years now and I have never seen a false negative.  Here is the complete function:

```
long IsDiskSpaceAvailable( const char* inDirectory, 
                           const _int64& inRequestedSize, 
                           _int64& outUserFree, 
                           _int64& outTotalFree, 
                           _int64& outCalcRequest  )
{
    ULARGE_INTEGER  fba;
    ULARGE_INTEGER  tnb;
    ULARGE_INTEGER  tnfba;
    ULARGE_INTEGER  reqsize;
    string          dir;
    size_t          len;

    dir = inDirectory;
    len = strlen( inDirectory );

    outUserFree     = 0;
    outTotalFree    = 0;
    outCalcRequest  = 0;

    if( inDirectory[len-1] != '\\' )
        dir += "\\";
    
    // this is the value of inRequestSize that was passed in
    // inRequestedSize = 3273917760;
    if( GetDiskFreeSpaceEx( dir.c_str(), &fba, &tnb, &tnfba ) )
    {
        outUserFree         = fba.QuadPart;
        outTotalFree        = tnfba.QuadPart;

        // this is computed dynamically given a specific compression
        // type, but for simplicity I had hard-coded the value that was used
        float compressionRatio = 10.0;
        reqsize.QuadPart = (ULONGLONG) (inRequestedSize / compressionRatio);
        outCalcRequest   = reqsize.QuadPart;

        // this is what was triggered to cause the failure,
        // i.e., user free space was < the request size
        if( fba.QuadPart < reqsize.QuadPart )
            return( RetCode_OutOfSpace );
    }
    else
    {
        return( RetCode_Failure );
    }
    
    return( RetCode_OK );
}
```

So, a value of `3273917760` was passed to the function which is the total amount of disk space needed before compression.  The function divides this by the compression ratio of `10` to get the actual size needed.

When I checked the disk that the share resides on it had ~177GB free, far more than what was reported.  After starting the test again without changing anything it worked.

So my question here is; what could cause something like this?  As far as I can tell it is not a programming error and, as I mentioned earlier, this code has been in use for a very long time now with no problems.

I checked the event log of the remote machine and found nothing of interest around the time of the failure.  I'm hoping that someone out there has seen something similar before, thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the disk had less space for the moment of time you got the failure.  For example, maybe a backup process (or malware scanner) had reserved a bunch of disk space, and then released it again when it finished.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Thanks Adrian.  This is the sort of thing I was hoping to find in the event log, but if there was something like that going on it wasn't logged.  I'm trying to come up with an explanation, but I just can't find any evidence of something funny going on.

Comment: Do you think the problem might be an integer signing issue?  The return value of the GetDiskFreeSpaceEx is an unsigned integer (ULONGLONG) which is 'typedef'ed to 'unsigned __int64'.  Wouldn't you be halving the amount that this can store by treating it as a signed value (i.e. via your return values)?

Comment: @AdrianConlon: Yes, it is, but seeing as it would still be 2^63 I don't think I have to worry about that for some time.

Answer (score 3):

Might not be of any use, but it's "strange" that:

177GB ~= 186580992 * 1000.

This could be explained by a stack corruption (since you don't initialize your local variable) happening elsewhere in the code.

The code "inRequestedSize / compressionRatio" doesn't have to be using float for the division, and since you've silented the "conversion loose precision" warning with the cast, you might actually hit an error too (but the number given in the example should work). You could simply do "inRequestedSize / 10".

Last but not least, you don't say where the code is running. On Mobile, the documentation of GetDiskFreeSpaceEx states:

> When Mobile Encryption is enabled, the reporting behavior of this function changes. Each encrypted file has at least one 4-KB page of overhead associated. This function takes this overhead into account when it reports the amount pf space available. That is, if a 128-KB disk contains a single 60-KB file, this function reports that 64 KB is available, subtracting the space occupied by both the file and its associated overhead.
>
> Although this function reports the total available space, keep the space requirement for encrypted files in mind when estimating whether multiple new files will fit into the remaining space. Include the amount of space required for overhead when Mobile Encryption is enabled. Each file requires at least an additional 4 KB. For example, a single 60-KB file requires 64 KB, but two 30-KB files actually require 68 KB.

Comment: You know I noticed that too and I have been looking down that track for the past day.  It's hard to imagine that this would pop up so subtly after so long, but of course it's possible and I agree that it being off by such a clean number is suspect. The code does actually need a float as the compression ratio is not always an integer, I just hard coded the value that was being used in the failure case for simplicity (it is actually returned by a function.).  This is on a PC, so no mobile, but I appreciate the response.

Comment: Ah... Is the compression ratio 0.1 then (and not 10) ? It could be a simple debugging error, misinterpreting the number.

Comment: And concerning the "Mobile" version, in fact, NTFS allow compression too, so the returned number is likely wrong if the drive is compressed.

Comment: In this case it was 10, but in others (depending on the compression type being used) it may be 7.5, 1.5, etc.